# How to root Android Device installed in Oracle VirtualBox on Windows

Tags: rooting, bluetooth-pairing, virtualbox

I have Android Device installed in Oracle VM VirtualBox on Windows 7. I need to pair two devices without user confirmation. It's Android 4.3. I want to connect two devices with Bluetooth and for that I need to pair them programatically first and I want to achieve this without the user having to press the pair button. My research so far has revealed that unless I have the root permissions I cannot pair two devices without user confirmation. So to achieve my target I want to root the virtual device I have installed on Windows 7. I have come across this thread: [xda-developers: How to root Android x86 4.3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2390619) that shows that it can be achieved on Ubuntu. Is there any way that I can achieve this on Windows 7 and make my virtual device rooted? Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for root Android-X86 use this :

[Download From XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2162360&stc=1&d=1375546952)

**Usage:** ROOT SCRIPT FOR ANDROID x86 4.3

```
On android-x86:
Boot up
Press ALT+F1 //or if doesnt work,download Terminal Emulator then open it and follow ...
"cd" to the folder containing this file
Run "sh install.sh" and follow the instructions

On a linux OS boot:
Open your linux terminal
"cd" to the folder containing this file
Run "sh install.sh" and follow the instructions
```

other links For more details :

[How to root device in Oracle VM Virtual Box](http://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-root-device-in-oracle-vm-virtual-box.815871/)

[How to Root Android Device installed in Oracle VM Virtual Box](https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-to-root-android-device-installed-in-oracle-vm-virtual-box/11912)

[How to root Android x86 4.3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2390619)
and ...

Comment: I have extracted the files and after pressing ALT+f1 in VM going to the terminal and typing the path(D:\Softwares\New folder) and then  when I type the command sh install.sh . I get a message "No such file or directory".. I am not able to figure it out why is it happening.. Any suggestions??

Comment: dude, you need extract this files in a directory on Android !,then, go to directory(With `cd` command) and run this install.sh.

Comment: @ Mohsen:I apologise for such a stupid question and how do I put this folder in Android VM and extract it there??

Comment: dont worry dude :) no problem, android x86 is a virtual and you can't share files on this but, you can find file link then download with browser and then with file manager or terminal find it.